# Creating model_form raises 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'query' error

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, wtforms

I'm using WTForms' `model_form` to create a form based on a Flask-SQLAlchemy model.  If there is a foreign key on the model, I get `AttributeError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'query'`.  Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

```
from wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.orm import model_form

class BREADView(MethodView):        
    def __init__(self,endpoint_param,model_param,exclude=None):
        self.endpoint = endpoint_param;
        self.model = model_param;        
        self.path = url_for('.%s' % self.endpoint)
        self.DetailForm = model_form(self.model, db_session=db, base_class=Form )
        self.DetailForm.submit = SubmitField('Submit')   

    def get(self, obj_id='', operation=''):
        if operation == 'new':        
            new_form = self.DetailForm(request.form)            
            return render_template(
                self.detail_template,
                form=new_form,
            )
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 130, in __call__
    self.error_log_file.logger.exception("Error running WSGI application")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 1296, in exception
    self.error(msg, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 1289, in error
    self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 1395, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 1404, in handle
    if (not self.disabled) and self.filter(record):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 692, in filter
    for f in self.filters:
  File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 122, in __call__
    app_iterator = self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/views.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/views.py", line 149, in dispatch_request
    return meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/severedblue/mysite/app/uct/views.py", line 53, in get
    endpoint=self.endpoint,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/templating.py", line 128, in render_template
    context, ctx.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/templating.py", line 110, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 969, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 742, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 36, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/severedblue/mysite/app/templates/form.html", line 2, in <module>
    {% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
  File "/home/severedblue/mysite/app/templates/base.html", line 1, in <module>
    {% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
  File "/home/severedblue/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_bootstrap/templates/bootstrap/base.html", line 1, in <module>
    {% block doc -%}
  File "/home/severedblue/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_bootstrap/templates/bootstrap/base.html", line 4, in <module>
    {%- block html %}
  File "/home/severedblue/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_bootstrap/templates/bootstrap/base.html", line 20, in <module>
    {% block body -%}
  File "/home/severedblue/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_bootstrap/templates/bootstrap/base.html", line 23, in <module>
    {% block content -%}
  File "/home/severedblue/mysite/app/templates/base.html", line 23, in <module>
    {% block page_content %}{% endblock %}
  File "/home/severedblue/mysite/app/templates/form.html", line 11, in <module>
    {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
  File "/home/severedblue/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_bootstrap/templates/bootstrap/wtf.html", line 195, in <module>
    {{ form_field(field,
  File "/home/severedblue/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_bootstrap/templates/bootstrap/wtf.html", line 116, in <module>
    {{field(class="form-control", **kwargs)|safe}}
  File "/home/severedblue/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 149, in __call__
    return self.meta.render_field(self, kwargs)
  File "/home/severedblue/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/wtforms/meta.py", line 53, in render_field
    return field.widget(field, **render_kw)
  File "/home/severedblue/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/wtforms/widgets/core.py", line 280, in __call__
    for val, label, selected in field.iter_choices():
  File "/home/severedblue/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/wtforms/ext/sqlalchemy/fields.py", line 107, in iter_choices
    for pk, obj in self._get_object_list():
  File "/home/severedblue/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/wtforms/ext/sqlalchemy/fields.py", line 98, in _get_object_list
    query = self.query or self.query_factory()
  File "/home/severedblue/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/wtforms/ext/sqlalchemy/orm.py", line 121, in <lambda>
    'query_factory': lambda: db_session.query(foreign_model).all()
AttributeError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'query'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've pointed `model_form` at the SQLAlchemy extension object, not the session it provides.  Use `db.session` instead.

```
self.DetailForm = model_form(self.model, db_session=db.session, base_class=Form)
```